# Embedding a flow in a DOJO dialog

Tags: spring, dojo, spring-webflow

I want to create a modal dialog wizard using spring web flow and dojo.

I searched for embedding the flow in a dialog using embedded mode. But I found very few examples related to this. In these examples, they used JSF dialogs and tiles framework to partially render a form.

Can we do this without using JSF and tiles framework but using jsp and dojo?
Can anyone help me to create a wizard embedded in a dojo dialog using spring web flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't depend on the dojo framework I believe is no longer supported with webflow. Moreover, webflow wasn't really designed (without hacks) to be embedded inside modal dialogs. It was designed as a simple "flow" navigation from html page to page.

To achieve what you want you'll have to use jquery (or some javascript library) to interact with the current flow via ajax calls to predefined transitions/fragments and manually via javascript take the response html fragments returned by webflow contents and change the contents of your modal dialog box. You could argue this is a "hack" but this is how I achieved what you desire using webflow.

A user asked a similar question a few months ago and i provided a thorough answer explaining how to use webflow + ajax + transitions in dialog boxes.

[How to include a pop-up dialog box in subflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000963/how-to-include-a-pop-up-dialog-box-in-subflow/29114719#29114719)