# Ajax Requests with Spring MVC + Spring Web Flow

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow-2

As a progressive enhancement I am attempting to apply AJAX in my Spring Web Flow. I am using:

- Spring Version 4.1.3
- Tiles version 2.2.2
- SWF version 2.4.1

While I am not entirely confident in my first attempt at the implementation of the SWF, Tiles and AJAX connections the SWF evaluate action appears to be executing correctly as my controller method is called, executed and returns success. On rendering the view I get an exception and am leaning toward a configuration issue  or I am grasping at straws after a full night of trying to debug. I will post my flow, jsp, ajax script, controller if needed.

Here is the full debug and stack trace

```
15:57:11.918 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.w.execution.AnnotatedAction - Clearing action execution attributes map[[empty]]
15:57:11.918 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor - Finished executing [EvaluateAction@373ffd expression = checkoutController.updateShipping(flowScope.checkoutForm, externalContext), resultExpression = [null]]; result = success
15:57:11.918 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor - Executing [RenderAction@14a2f78 fragments = array<Expression>[shipping-table]]
15:57:11.918 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.w.execution.AnnotatedAction - Putting action execution attributes map[[empty]]
15:57:11.918 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.w.execution.AnnotatedAction - Clearing action execution attributes map[[empty]]
15:57:11.918 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor - Finished executing [RenderAction@14a2f78 fragments = array<Expression>[shipping-table]]; result = success
15:57:11.918 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.webflow.engine.Transition - Executing [Transition@1728a9d on = updateShipping, to = [null]]
15:57:11.918 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.webflow.engine.ViewState - Rendering + [ServletMvcView@1544f9e view = org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView: name 'checkout/shippingOptions'; URL [checkout/shippingOptions]]
15:57:11.918 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.webflow.engine.ViewState -   Flash scope = map['flowRenderFragments' -> array<String>['shipping-table']]
15:57:11.918 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.webflow.engine.ViewState -   Messages = [DefaultMessageContext@ea5678 sourceMessages = map[[null] -> list[[empty]]]]
15:57:11.918 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView - Rendering MVC [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView: name 'checkout/shippingOptions'; URL [checkout/shippingOptions]] with model map [{flowRequestContext=[RequestControlContextImpl@d2f858 externalContext = org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.MvcExternalContext@c29d0d, currentEvent = updateShipping, requestScope = map[[empty]], attributes = map[[empty]], messageContext = [DefaultMessageContext@ea5678 sourceMessages = map[[null] -> list[[empty]]]], flowExecution = [FlowExecutionImpl@ae672a flow = 'checkout', flowSessions = list[[FlowSessionImpl@1f6fef4 flow = 'checkout', state = 'shippingOptions', scope = map['viewScope' -> map[[empty]], 'checkoutForm' -> com.twelves.bazaar.web.form.CheckoutForm@d4c1e5]]]]], flashScope=map['flowRenderFragments' -> array<String>['shipping-table']], org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.checkoutForm=org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.BindingModel: 0 errors, currentUser=org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8c3df917: Principal: com.twelves.bazaar.web.security.BazaarUserDetails@6b213b; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe3f86: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: D094AF98D22C71E3C35B5D8EDCEA3930; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ROOT, PERM_CREATE_ORDER, PERM_MANAGE_CONTENT, PERM_ROOT, checkoutForm=com.twelves.bazaar.web.form.CheckoutForm@d4c1e5, flowRenderFragments=[Ljava.lang.String;@dc5ab2, flowExecutionKey=e1s2, flowExecutionUrl=/bazaar-app/checkout?execution=e1s2, viewScope=map[[empty]]}]
15:57:11.919 [tomcat-http--15] TRACE o.s.w.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView - Rendering view with name 'checkout/shippingOptions' with model {flowRequestContext=[RequestControlContextImpl@d2f858 externalContext = org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.MvcExternalContext@c29d0d, currentEvent = updateShipping, requestScope = map[[empty]], attributes = map[[empty]], messageContext = [DefaultMessageContext@ea5678 sourceMessages = map[[null] -> list[[empty]]]], flowExecution = [FlowExecutionImpl@ae672a flow = 'checkout', flowSessions = list[[FlowSessionImpl@1f6fef4 flow = 'checkout', state = 'shippingOptions', scope = map['viewScope' -> map[[empty]], 'checkoutForm' -> com.twelves.bazaar.web.form.CheckoutForm@d4c1e5]]]]], flashScope=map['flowRenderFragments' -> array<String>['shipping-table']], org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.checkoutForm=org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.BindingModel: 0 errors, currentUser=org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8c3df917: Principal: com.twelves.bazaar.web.security.BazaarUserDetails@6b213b; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe3f86: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: D094AF98D22C71E3C35B5D8EDCEA3930; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ROOT, PERM_CREATE_ORDER, PERM_MANAGE_CONTENT, PERM_ROOT, checkoutForm=com.twelves.bazaar.web.form.CheckoutForm@d4c1e5, flowRenderFragments=[Ljava.lang.String;@dc5ab2, flowExecutionKey=e1s2, flowExecutionUrl=/bazaar-app/checkout?execution=e1s2, viewScope=map[[empty]]} and static attributes {}
15:57:11.919 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.w.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView - Added model object 'flowRequestContext' of type [org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl] to request in view with name 'checkout/shippingOptions'
15:57:11.919 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.w.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView - Added model object 'flashScope' of type [org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap] to request in view with name 'checkout/shippingOptions'
15:57:11.919 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.w.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView - Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.checkoutForm' of type [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.BindingModel] to request in view with name 'checkout/shippingOptions'
15:57:11.919 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.w.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView - Added model object 'currentUser' of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken] to request in view with name 'checkout/shippingOptions'
15:57:11.919 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.w.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView - Added model object 'checkoutForm' of type [com.twelves.bazaar.web.form.CheckoutForm] to request in view with name 'checkout/shippingOptions'
15:57:11.919 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.w.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView - Added model object 'flowRenderFragments' of type [[Ljava.lang.String;] to request in view with name 'checkout/shippingOptions'
15:57:11.919 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.w.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView - Added model object 'flowExecutionKey' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'checkout/shippingOptions'
15:57:11.919 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.w.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView - Added model object 'flowExecutionUrl' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'checkout/shippingOptions'
15:57:11.919 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.w.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView - Added model object 'viewScope' of type [org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap] to request in view with name 'checkout/shippingOptions'
15:57:11.942 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.w.c.i.SessionBindingConversationManager - Unlocking conversation 1
15:57:11.942 [tomcat-http--15] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Cleared thread-bound request context: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper@36252c]
15:57:11.946 [tomcat-http--15] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1287) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868) [spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [catalina.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42.A]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:76) ~[servlet-api.jar:3.0.FR]
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:76) ~[servlet-api.jar:3.0.FR]
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:76) ~[servlet-api.jar:3.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver.parseLocaleCookieIfNecessary(CookieLocaleResolver.java:150) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver.resolveLocale(CookieLocaleResolver.java:130) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getLocale(RequestContextUtils.java:121) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringLocaleResolver.resolveLocale(SpringLocaleResolver.java:54) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.getDefinition(UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.java:102) ~[tiles-core-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.getDefinition(BasicTilesContainer.java:364) ~[tiles-core-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.isValidDefinition(BasicTilesContainer.java:706) ~[tiles-core-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.isValidDefinition(BasicTilesContainer.java:350) ~[tiles-core-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:169) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView.flattenAttributeMap(AjaxTilesView.java:173) ~[spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to implement ajax requests in SWF utilizing SWF's render fragments='...' tag in the ajax call -> transition -> fragment render pattern. The nice thing about this solution is it is already built in SWF so no need for hacks or enhancements.

see: [How to include a pop-up dialog box in subflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000963/how-to-include-a-pop-up-dialog-box-in-subflow)